# Is there any way to avoid ng-repeat in this particular case?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

In the particular case that I really know that this filter will return only one ocurrence, is there any way to use do this in a better way? Maybe with other directive?

```
<div ng-repeat="category in product.categories | filter: { name: userChoice }">
```

http://jsfiddle.net/cjy8o4t1/

This is the Javascript

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

function MyCtrl($scope) {

    $scope.userChoice='computers';

    $scope.product=
        {
            id: 'sku908398939',
            categories:[
                {
                    name: 'computers',
                    val: {
                        minQty: 10,
                        maxQty: 100
                    }
                },
                {
                    name: 'hifi',
                    val: {
                        minQty: 20,
                        maxQty: 200
                    }                        
                }

            ]
        }
}
```

This is the view:

```
<div data-ng-controller="MyCtrl" ng-app="myApp">

    <select ng-model="userChoice" ng-options="c.name as c.name for c in product.categories">
    </select>

    <div ng-repeat="category in product.categories | filter: { name: userChoice }">
       Min qty for category {{category.name}} is {{category.val.minQty}} units
    </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Do you mean use filter outside of an ng-repeat? That is possible to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you are just trying to match the information of the object bound to your dropdown list.  Just change the way you bind to your `userChoice` object (bind the whole object instead of just the property) and display that.  This way you don't even have to work with the array yourself.

HTML

```
<select ng-model="userChoice" ng-options="c as c.name for c in product.categories">
</select>
<div>
    Min qty for category {{userChoice.name}} is {{userChoice.val.minQty}} units
</div>
```

You can also add this to you controller to better default the dropdown object.

```
$scope.userChoice= $scope.product.categories[0];
```

[Editted fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6zwmfy5c/1/)

Comment: Thanks. Just what I want to achieve.

Answer (score 1):

No need for filter or ng-repeat in this case. Just use ng-options ability to bind to an object:

```
<select ng-model="userChoice" ng-options="c as c.name for c in product.categories">
</select>
```

Now `userChoice` is one of the objects from the array:

```
Min qty for category {{userChoice.name}} is {{userChoice.val.minQty}} units
```

Check this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ag10k71s/)

Comment: Thanks. Just what I want to achieve. Your explanation clarified me the use of ng-options.